# Как в c++(QThread.run()) вызвать функцию из qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qthread

Мне нужно в новом потоке(QThread) создавать с периодичностью в 5 сек новый елемент(обычную точку) в компоненте qml
В самом qml это сделать не так сложно , я использовал такую функцию:

```
function getRandomInt(min,max) { //! Getting random positions
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
    }

    function loadingPoints(x,y) {   //! Loading Points into window
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Points.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var button = component.createObject(_customComponent , {"x": getRandomInt(10,x), "y": getRandomInt(10,y) , color: "red"});
        }
    }
```

Points.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

    Rectangle { //! Definition of circle(point)
        property real diameter: 5
         width: diameter
         height: diameter
         radius: diameter
         color: "blue"
    }
```

MyThread.h

```
#include <QThread>

#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H


class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread() : m_quit(false) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE void quit() {
        m_quit = true;
    }

protected:
    void run();

private:
    volatile bool m_quit; //! volantile - informing compiler that value of variable can change from outside

signals:
    void drawPoints(int x, int y);   
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

MyThread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQuickItem>


void MyThread::run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        qDebug() << i;
        emit drawPoints(i,i);
        msleep(500);
    }

}
```

Comment: Я полагаю, что это бессмысленно. Отрисовка всего графического контента все равно выполняется в отдельном потоке, поэтому создавать точки в отдельном потоке кажется бессмысленным. В вашем случае нужно менять полностью идеологию. Нужно создавать контейнер, который будет отрисовываться  в qml, а вот заполнение контейнера может происходить в отдельном потоке.

Comment: А как сделать это заполнение в отдельном потоке , оно и так заполняет отдельный контейнер , отрисованный в qml , у меня проблема вызова функции qml из с++ кода